# how to extract parameter value from firebase dynamic link email directly in android activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have searched SO a lot but could not find a similar type question. My requirement is simple. I need to get parameter values from Email from my mailbox.My Email look like follows:

https://ejr3J.app.goo.gl/Rerjk?userId=qE721dmnre2dfmd_fdare55EnDB&session=ZwlkEL54_danbreMEdneENfdfm

When i click on this link it opens the desired activity (deep-linked activity) and getting also the deep link url (www.example.com) but cannot retrieve the parameters values (values of userId and session). I've tried to get the value using deeplinkUri.getQueryParameter("userId"), but it returns null value. Please help to accomplish this task. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wrong in create dynamic link step.

Instead of add parameter to shortlink after it is generated, you must attach parameter in the link url (www.example.com). Like this: www.example.com?userId=qE721dmnre2dfmd_fdare55EnDB&session=ZwlkEL54_danbreMEdneENfdfm; After that, you generate dynamic link.